# Hanging a 45lbs mirror to drywall

Tags: screws, drywall-anchor, mirror

What is the best way to hang a 45lbs mirror (*Ikea Hovet*) to the wall?

I'm   new to this and attempted to use a flip toggle but I had the wrong size screw. I've since figured out that I need a #8 screw but I'm wondering if it needs to be a particular length?

I have #8 that is 1 1/4" with some screw in anchors that sat 25lbs horizontally 63lbs vertically. Would this anchor and screw combo work for me?

Ideally how long of a screw would I need for this weight?

thank you!

Comment: How many points of support are you trying to hang the mirror from?  You might want anything from a plastic drywall insert to maybe a screw in insert or move up to a toggle bolt or preferably screw into a stud if you haven't ruled out the possiblity.

Comment: #8 is minimum, you can use even #10. The best way to hang so heavy items is to put screws to studs if it is possble. If not ,, use something like toggle bolts or similar anchors, not "easy anchors".

Comment: I'd consider a french cleat for hanging a mirror.

Comment: These come with their own screw. They are rated for 265 lbs in 1/2-in drywall. - https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831

Comment: This mirror?  -  https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/hovet-mirror-aluminum-50038213/

Answer (score 1):

Toggle bolts and Ez screw in anchors can be used if the studs don’t Line up where you want. Static vertical loads on sheetrock walls are what Ez anchors or self drilling anchors are really good at holding.

Make you use the correct sized and type (plastic or metal anchors).
I prefer Ez anchors in the rentals as they are less work to repair when new renters move in (unscrew them and patch the hole) verses drilling some types out or pushing through and having to fix a much larger hole.

I have no affiliation with Ez anchors or self drilling anchors but have used them in my own home and rentals. There are small and large sized anchors make to use the appropriate one for the load being supported.

Comment: I would not trust an EZ  anchor with a 45lb mirror.

Comment: Since some are rated to 75 lbs you must have only have limited experience with the little plastic ones. Just saying as I have used them many times and have not had a recall for a failure on professional jobs. And have had no failures with mine and the ones I have installed for my family.

Comment: Ed, i am not questioning your experience. I am simply stating that I do not think they are to be trusted with a 45lb mirror when the alternative is better and cost little more. I will use them for certain things, i always pilot drill a  small hole for them as  they tend to chew up and pulverize the drywall as they bore into it.

Answer (score 0):

This mirror is 70cm wide, studs are every 60cm, so you will have at least one stud somewhere behind the mirror.

Since this mirror (Ikea Hovet) is mounted on a hollow box, there is enough room inside to put a french cleat (ie, a piece of wood) against the wall. It does not matter if the stud is exactly in the center of the mirror, it you screw the piece of wood in the stud, this screw will hold all the weight and all the traction load. You can add a screw into the drywall at both ends to prevent it from rotating and keep it level. These screws will hold a much lighter load, and zero traction load since that's all on the stud, so they don't need heavy duty anchors.

Comment: I love me some french cleat, How would this DEE -IY'er attach the other half of the french cleat to the hollow backside of this particular mirror?

Comment: Check how the hollow metal frame of the mirror is made

Comment: This is a good idea for this mirror.   The mirror can be attached to its half of the cleat with two screws exactly the way it would attach to the wall.

Comment: What is "traction load"? Not a term I'm familiar with. Could be a simple translation and/or regional usage thing...

Comment: Clumsy translation from French on my part. It means the load force pulls on the fastener, which is okay if the screw is in a stud, but not really great for drywall. What's the proper term?

Answer (score 0):

Normally on this type of installation I would use a french cleat. It's the easiest and most secure method of putting up a heavy wall hanging. In reviewing the Hovet mirror Ikea isn't clear on what type hangers are provided or whether additional brackets can be added by screwing them into the polystyrene backing.
Assuming you can't use a french cleat here are several important recommendations.

- Whether you hang it vertically or horizontally you want to try to have **at least** two anchor points in studs.
- If you can only get into one stud I would try to make that the central point of attachment with at least two other attach points, one on each side using hollow wall toggles.
- For the stud attachment there are a number of good heavy duty hooks that will work. Get one rated at least 75 lbs. Always better to be safe.

Comment: Imagine that, IKEA instructions that are not clear.